# Position the icons in the center of the taskbar?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I would like to position the icons on my taskbar win 10 in the center of the desktop but this is only possible manually can i do that with vb.net  like famous TaskbarX from github i wonder if i can do the same with the vb.net?

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1tTN.jpg)

just like in the picture above but with a vb.net.

Comment: Isn't that Project built using VB.Net? Download it and give it a look. It's just some Win32 API calls and UI Automation.

Comment: It seems that you need to use [shappbarmessage](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/shappbarmessage.html). Check [this reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2b38ab35-f638-407d-a59a-e93a1c1b8517/how-could-i-make-a-desktop-toolbar-in-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral)